# Is it possible and safe to use LED control button for PC restart

Tags: desktop-computer, case, led

I have PC case that has only 2 buttons: power and LED control. My LED is controlled via motherboard software, so i have LED button disabled now. Can i plug it in restart pin on motherboard? Will it be safe, maybe i should perform any additional checks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Electrically it's safe. They're all simple push buttons: all they do is connect two wires together.

The unsafe part is other people accidentally resetting your computer when they try to control LEDs.